# Making a Multiple Select Control Sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, extjs

Does anyone know how to make a multiple select (see below HTML) sortable?  Using either jQuery or Ext JS?  By sortable, I mean that I can drag an item (an option) up or down to reposition it in the select control.

```
<select id="testing" multiple=multiple>
    <option>First Option</option>
    <option>Second Option</option>
    <option>Third Option</option>
    <option>Forth Option</option>
    <option>5 Option</option>
    <option>6 Option</option>
    <option>7 Option</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it reliably with drag-and-drop. `<select multiple>` may be implemented using an OS select-list widget, which will not typically generate `mouse` events like the native HTML elements do.

You'd have to replace the `<select>` with a load of `<div>` analogues for it, which do provide sortability in the normal way whichever library/plugin you want to use for it does. It's a fair bit of bother to make an ersatz-`<select>` nicely accessible/usable/keyboardable though; most plugins don't really manage to fully.

The simpler alternative would be simply to have separate ‘Move up’/‘Move down’ buttons, which find and move the selected `<option>`​s in the element.

Comment: Yes, I thought about simply including a set of "Move up/Move down' buttons.  But I'm trying to not go down that route because it's a negative impact on usability.  Unless the up/down buttons are shown within the option item, then it's a little easier for the user.

Comment: I was afraid that I need to go down the <div> route in order to make a list of items sortable, but I don't think I have a choice here.

Answer (score 6):

### ✅✅ [selectize/selectize.js](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js)

This can be attached to text (freetagging) as well as to select. I does have drag_drop and remove_button plugins.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
    $('select').selectize({
      plugins: ['remove_button', 'drag_drop']
  });
});
</script><select multiple>
<option value ="1">One</option>
<option value ="2" selected>Two</option>
<option value ="3" selected>Three</option>
</select>
```

### ✅ [jshjohnson/Choices](https://github.com/jshjohnson/Choices)

This can be attached to a select element and has an *ordered* option which then rewrites the order of the select options. So your selections are returned in the order you select them. Drag-and-drop is not possible though and [will not be implemented](https://github.com/jshjohnson/Choices/issues/417).

### Other libraries that show the order of selection in the UI but do not allow drag-and-drop nor seem to change the select accordingly

- [Dropdown | Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html) ([1](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/3841), [2](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/5166))
- [jQuery Dropdown | Dane](https://dane.one/projects/jquery-dropdown/demo/)
- [Fastselect](http://dbrekalo.github.io/fastselect/)
- [Light Weight MultiSelect Test Page](http://keyo321.github.io/jQueryLightWeightMultiSelect/)

### Other select libraries that sort their options and do not respect ordering in the first place

- [tail.select](https://github.com/wolffe/tail.select.js)
- [jQuery Pretty Dropdowns Demo](https://thdoan.github.io/pretty-dropdowns/demo.html)
- [creativecirclemedia/dropdown-checkboxes](https://github.com/creativecirclemedia/dropdown-checkboxes)
- [jQuery Selectric](http://selectric.js.org/)
- [Jquery.sumoselect by Hemant Negi](http://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/)

### Unknown but unlikely

- [jQuery Selectpick](http://project.zyy1217.com/selectpick/)
- https://prevwong.github.io/awesome-select/
- [PebbleRoad/combo-select](https://github.com/PebbleRoad/combo-select)
- [zeusdeux/fuzzy-dropdown](https://github.com/zeusdeux/fuzzy-dropdown)
- [ddSlick](https://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick#demo)
- [Hierarchy Select jQuery Plugin for Twitter Bootstrap 4](https://neofusion.github.io/hierarchy-select/)
- [BenMMcLean/BetterSelecter](https://github.com/BenMMcLean/BetterSelecter)
- [bschueller/jquery.selectMe](https://github.com/bschueller/jquery.selectMe)

Comment: The mentioned **tail.select** script allows to "pin" selected options on the top of the dropdown list using `multiPinSelected: true`, but a respective [plugin](https://github.com/pytesNET/tail.select/issues/73) to drag'n'drop the dropdown / container options is currently in development for Version 1.0.0. :D

Comment: I would like to note a change for the `tail.select` library. The old repository is gone completely and the new version is here -

https://github.com/wolffe/tail.select.js

Also, the demo is available here -

https://getbutterfly.com/tail-select/

Since the plugin has disappeared, a few months ago, I have updated it to version 0.5.20 and an ES6 version 0.6 is in the works. I am maintaining this plugin/library full time.

Comment: @Ciprian Link is updated. This sounds like great news. Do you have any priorities as of that feature?

Comment: @geek-merlin Not yet, I am still working on changing everything to ES6 and modern browsers support only.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI has functions for making things sortable. See http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/.

Comment: Right, so how do you do it?  The examples only show that it is possible for <ul> and <div>, but <select multiple> is a bit different.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution from internet after some study and search. Please try the following one -

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#move-up').click(moveUp);
        $('#move-down').click(moveDown);
    });

    function moveUp() {
        $('#selected-items select :selected').each(function(i, selected) {
            if (!$(this).prev().length) return false;
            $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev());
        });
        $('#selected-items select').focus().blur();
    }

    function moveDown() {
        $($('#selected-items select :selected').get().reverse()).each(function(i, selected) {
            if (!$(this).next().length) return false;
            $(this).insertAfter($(this).next());
        });
        $('#selected-items select').focus().blur();
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="selected">
        <div><strong>Selected</strong></div>
        <div id="selected-items">
            <select multiple="multiple" id="selected_fields" name="selected_fields[]">
                <option>one</option>
                <option>two</option>
                <option>three</option>
                <option>four</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="priority">
        <div><input type="button" id="move-up" value="UP" /></div>
        <div><input type="button" id="move-down" value="DOWN" /></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```